# Ionic 5, how to get the serial number of device via capacitor?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm building an app by using Ionic 5 & CapacitorJs, I want to know how to get the serial number via the capacitor plugin?

I don't want to use the Cordova plugin if possible.

Comment: use Cordova Device plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device . as per capacitor device plugin serial is not available.

Comment: open "https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device" click on capacitor tab install plugin

Add in `app.module.ts` file inside `providers`

Import in `constructor`  `public device: Device`

get serial using `this.device.serial`

Comment: There isn't any real "Serial Number" especially starting from Android 10. IMEI and MAC Address are hidden or randomly generated each time them ar used, and other UUID (Unique IDs) changes at each Device Factory Reset. So which "Serial Number" do you need?

Comment: @emandt Thanks for the information, what about IOS? because previously we used Cordova plugin, which has a serial field...when I switch to the capacitor, I find the Device plugin does not have a field called serial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read IMEI, ICCID, IMSI and MAC with Ionic Device

First of all you need to install plugins

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-uid
$ npm install @ionic-native/uid

$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions
$ npm install @ionic-native/android-permissions
```

Or with capacitor:

```
npm install @ionic-native/android-permissions
npm install cordova-plugin-android-permissions
npm install cordova-plugin-uid
npm install @ionic-native/uid

ionic cap sync
```

So you need to implement something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id/ngx';
    import { Uid } from '@ionic-native/uid/ngx';
    import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
    })
    export class HomePage {
    
      constructor(
        private uniqueDeviceID: UniqueDeviceID,
        private uid: Uid,
        private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions
      ) {
      }
    
        ...
        ...
    
    }
```

And

```
  getPermission(){
    this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(
      this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
    ).then(res => {
      if(res.hasPermission){
        
      }else{
        this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE).then(res => {
          alert("Persmission Granted Please Restart App!");
        }).catch(error => {
          alert("Error! "+error);
        });
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      alert("Error! "+error);
    });
  }
```

And

```
  getID_UID(type){
    if(type == "IMEI"){
      return this.uid.IMEI;
    }else if(type == "ICCID"){
      return this.uid.ICCID;
    }else if(type == "IMSI"){
      return this.uid.IMSI;
    }else if(type == "MAC"){
      return this.uid.MAC;
    }else if(type == "UUID"){
      return this.uid.UUID;
    }
  }
```

OR MAYBE BETTER

```
getID_UID = (type) => (this.uid[type])
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, do I have to install a Cordova plugin? Is there any capacitor plugin I can use for this scenario?

Comment: Capacitor supports Cordova plugins too!!

You only need to install them like this:

npm install cordova-plugin-uid
npm install @ionic-native/uid
ionic cap sync

Comment: @NiccolòBiagi get imei number app restart is  neccessary..?? i ther any fix